# Use a variable created using javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using JavaScript I get the selected value of this `select`:

```html
<select class="form-control pull-right" name="Type" id="Type" tabindex="" >
    <option>-Type-</option>
    <option value="1">Re</option>
    <option value="2">Cre</option>
    <option value="3">Ca</option>
</select>
```

```js
var drop = document.getElementById("Type")
alert(drop.value)
```

I want use the variable gotten by JavaScript in the same HTML file. How can I do it?

In HTML I want something like this:

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    {{.TYPE.Account_Number}}
</div>
```

so that while displaying Account number is dynamic depending on the selected value

Comment: Please make your question more clearer, what stopping you from reusing the variable?

Comment: Are you using the variable in another script tag? What's your attempt and what's the problem? Please share your code about re-using with us.

Comment: can u see my updated question

Comment: all these are in one same html page.. and after selecting a value from dropdown..account number should be displayed with corresponding type

Comment: @joyBlanks printing is not my aim here...using the selected value in html is my aim

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but here is a start point for you.
Use some [jQuery events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/) to hook the user actions to the code - in this case I would use `change()` event to display the selected value dynamically on the page.

Here is a sample code and demo:

[**JSnippet Demo**](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/327/)

```
$('#Type').change(function(){

    //Get selected value:
    var selectedValue = $(this).val(); 
    var selectedText  = $(this).children(":selected").text();

    //Set result:
    $('div').text(
        "Type Value:" + selectedValue + 
        " Type name:" + selectedText
    );

});
```